# How do I implement basic camera operations in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, graphics, camera

I'm trying to implement an application using OpenGL and I need to implement the basic camera movements: orbit, pan and zoom.

To make it a little clearer, I need Maya-like camera control. Due to the nature of the application, I can't use the good ol' "transform the scene to make it look like the camera moves". So I'm stuck using transform matrices, gluLookAt, and such.

Zoom I know is dead easy, I just have to hook to the depth component of the eye vector (gluLookAt), but I'm not quite sure how to implement the other two, pan and orbit. Has anyone ever done this?

Answer (score 3):

> I can't use the good ol' "transform the scene to make it look like the camera moves"

OpenGL has no camera. So you'll end up doing exactly this.

> Zoom I know is dead easy, I just have to hook to the depth component of the eye vector (gluLookAt),

This is not a Zoom, this is a Dolly. Zooming means varying the limits of the projection volume, i.e. the extents of a ortho projection, or the field of view of a perspective.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually not entirely sure about the names I used. So "Zoom" is Dolly, are the other names correct?

Comment: Yes, if you refer panning to as rotating the camera in place, orbiting as letting the camera circle around an object always facing it. Dolly means moving the camera (also along the viewing axis). Note that all these work in orthographic projection as well. But a camera dolly along the viewing axis won't change the picture in ortho, whereas with a perspective it will "enlarge" objects. However zooming is changing the view limits and works in ortho and perspective alike.

Answer (score 1):

gluLookAt, which you've already run into, is your solution.  First three arguments are the camera's position (x,y,z), next three are the camera's center (the point it's looking at), and the final three are the up vector (usually (0,1,0)), which defines the *camera*'s y-z plane.*

It's pretty simple: you just glLoadIdentity();, call gluLookAt(...), and then draw your scene as normally.  Personally, I always do all the calculations in the CPU myself.  I find that orbiting a point is an extremely common task.  My template C/C++ code uses spherical coordinates and looks like:

```
double camera_center[3] = {0.0,0.0,0.0};
double camera_radius = 4.0;
double camera_rot[2] = {0.0,0.0};
double camera_pos[3] = {
    camera_center[0] + camera_radius*cos(radians(camera_rot[0]))*cos(radians(camera_rot[1])),
    camera_center[1] + camera_radius*                            sin(radians(camera_rot[1])),
    camera_center[2] + camera_radius*sin(radians(camera_rot[0]))*cos(radians(camera_rot[1]))
};
gluLookAt(
       camera_pos[0],   camera_pos[1],   camera_pos[2],
    camera_center[0],camera_center[1],camera_center[2],
    0,1,0
);
```

Clearly you can adjust camera_radius, which will change the "zoom" of the camera, camera_rot, which will change the rotation of the camera about its axes, or camera_center, which will change the point about which the camera orbits.

*The only other tricky bit is learning *exactly* what all that means.  To clarify, because the internet is lacking:

- The position is the (x,y,z) position of the camera.  Pretty straightforward.
- The center is the (x,y,z) point the camera is focusing at.  You're basically looking along an imaginary ray *from* the position *to* the center.
- Now, your camera could still be looking any direction *around* this vector (e.g., it could be upsidedown, but still looking along the same direction).  The up vector is a vector, *not* a position.  It, along with that imaginary vector from the position to the center, form a plane.  This is the camera's y-z plane.